# Views Output Field as Link: Change link text

Tags: 7, views

I've got a View showing some images. I want to include a link to the image which automatically downloads the file. I'm using the [DownloadFile](http://drupal.org/project/download_file) module which makes sure the browser actually downloads the image instead of just displaying it.

I've added the Image field that I want displayed in my View, and I'm checking the `Output this field as a link` but I don't see any field where I can control the link text. I see title, rel, etc., but I want the actual link text to simply say "Download".

i.e.:

```
<a href='...'>Download</a>
```

How can I control the link text of the link being rendered by Views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While editing your view, open the field you want to modify.  In your case it would be your Image field that current output's `<a href='...'>Download</a>`

Scroll to 'Rewrite Results' and check the box next to 'Rewrite the output of this field.'

Enter the text that you would like to display instead of 'Download.'

I believe if you use the [Tokens](http://drupal.org/project/token) module, you will have several variables accessible to you as well.  See "Replacement Patterns" in the same menu to see what is available.

[image]